# find model on a collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a set of models that are added to a collection via a server call. All my models are added and are tracing out to be in the collection. Now I want a way to lookup the collections and return a model based on a specified id attribute inside the model. I'm not talking about the collections built in id. I'm refering to a custom id that is part of each model in the collection.

So fare I have this. but my _detect function is not returning what I'm after.

```
    var collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({


        initialize: function( ) {
            _.bindAll(this);
            this.bind('add', this.modelIsAddedd);
            this.serverCall();
        },

        modelIsAddedd: function(model){
            console.log('model = ', model);
        },

        getModelByCustomID: function( id ){

            var model = this.detect( id, function( model ){ return model });

        },

        serverCall: function(){

            $.ajax({
                my ajax call with success and error

            });
        },

        onSuccess: function(response){
            this.add(response.data);
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: Is this custom id unique across all models in the system? Can you make it the model's `id` via `idAttribute`?

Comment: Yes the customID is unique to each model in the collection.

Answer (score 3):

Ok figured it out just in case anyone else needs the answer.

```
getModelByCustomID: function( id ){

        var model = this.detect( function( model ){ 
            return model.get('customIDName') == id;
        });

},
```

Comment: FYI what you are looking for is available out of the box: if you set your model's `idAttribute` property to `"customIDName"`, you'll not only have the convenience of `myModel.id` being a shortcut to `myModel.get('customIDName')`, you'd also be able to use the super fast, hash-based [`Collection.get(id)` method](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-get) (that you've re-invented here).

Comment: I didn't know you could set model.idAttribute = "customID"

Comment: GENIUS! Just wasted hours on this. Should have read the docs!